# Smooth scroll in Zathura

Tags: zathura

I am trying to enable the smooth scrolling feature in Zathura. I have the following line in my zathurarc: `set smooth-scroll true`, but the scrolling doesn't become smooth.

According to the documentation:

> smooth-scroll
>
> Defines if scrolling via touchpad should be smooth(only available with gtk >= 3.4).

I have gtk 3.22 installed (which is greater than 3.4, right?) as `dpkg -s libgtk-3-0|grep '^Version'` gives me `Version: 3.22.4-1`.

What do I need to do in order to enable smooth scroll? The "via touchpad" part is also suspicious, but I can't get it to work on either a touchpad, a scrollwheel or with the keyboard.

Another suspicious thing is that it does not autocomplete when I type `:set sm` which it does with other options.

Comment: can you try setting a verbose error-log level? Maybe that would give you a hint about the underlying problem.  Also, have you observed problems with other applications and the scroll-speed?

Comment: In newer releases of Zathura (0.4.3) the scrolling is now smooth by default. Still no smooth-scroll option.

Comment: @ILMostro_7: Nope, I don't see anything suspicious with verbose logging and nope, no other applications are behaving strange.

Comment: @Heilke Walinga: Hmm... Strange! I am running 0.4.3 and the scrolling is not smooth. So... Is it smooth for you, you say?

Comment: @nijoakim Sorry to bother you, were you able to find a workaround to enable smooth scrolling in zathura ?

Comment: @Atralb: You are welcome to bother! :) Unfortunately I haven't, though. If i ever find one, I will post it here.

Answer (score 3):

I've just updated to the latest version (zathura 0.4.4, girara 0.3.3) and I'm now getting:

```
warning: Unknown option: smooth-scroll
```

this seems to be because of [a change to girara](https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/girara/commit/c4594beb8d205cf2635e1ba2e7c55196c3fc5b18) that made smooth scrolling always be turned on

looks like we can just remove this line from our config files now!

Answer (score 2):

I use the touchpad and had the same problem. this got it fixed though:

```
:set scroll-step 50
```

(you can fiddle with the number to see which suits you the best)

Comment: Hmm... According to the man page, that should have nothing to do with smoothness, and the default value is 40; I don't see why 50 would make a difference. I have tried it anyway, but that doesn't change the smoothness.

Answer (score -2):

You have to put double quotes around `true`

```
set smooth-scroll "true"
```

From `man zathurarc`

```
   COMMANDS
   set - Changing options
   ...   
      · BOOL - A boolean value ("true" for true, "false" for false)
```

Comment: Seems unlikely.  I did [a Google search for `zathurarc`](https://www.google.com/search?q=zathurarc), and [the first hit](https://github.com/majutsushi/etc/blob/master/zathurarc "etc/zathurarc at master · majutsushi/etc · GitHub") shows examples of `set … true` *without* quotes.  Can you give a reference that supports your answer?  (Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.) Can anybody verify that this works?

Comment: Hmm... I tried it but I don't see a difference. Thanks for your answer, though, and feel free to elaborate if you think that I have misunderstood something.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a reference from the man page. Also note that `smooth-scroll` does not enable smooth scrolling with vim-like motion keys. It only enables with trackpad.

Comment: This isn't true. Zathura errors when you give it a bad value, which it does not do for just writing ```true``` instead of ```"true"```. Also this doesn't work.

Comment: @vn-ki This is wrong. The double quotes are just a convention to unambiguously tell exactly what should be actually written in the config file : what is inside the double quotes. Unfortunately it can also be ambiguous when this convention is not clearly stated beforehand in the document.